# How to detect if a variable is already declared in Pascal Script?

Tags: variables, pascalscript, declare, defined

I have a small application that runs Pascal Script blocks and I need to know if a variable has been declared before. I have not found any functions in Pascal Script that indicate whether a variable has been declared.

Comment: Martin, I need this because my software has a introduction of scripts with pascalscript, and the user can modify this. With this test I reduce the number of errors for the scripts execution.

Comment: That's still rather vague. Consider asking more specific question about the specific problem you are solving. I'm answering you literal question now.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I Use FastReport in my application to building reports. In FastReport I Use PascalScript in code for a modify the reports. FastReports has two folders, in the first folder design de report in visual mode, in this configuration, I can put a control with text and assign a variable to control, in second folder I have code to modifi propierties of this control, if the user delete de control in first folder, then the report causes a bug because the "variable" of control does not exist. If PascalScript has a function that detect if variable is declarated or not, I Can control this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, programming languages do not have ways to test, if a variable has been declared before.

I believe Pascal Script does not have such feature either.